# jconsole connecting to ipv6 JMX service URL

Tags: java, remoting, jmx, ipv6

I have trouble connecting to a JMX Service URL having an IPv6 address through jconsole.  I tried

```
service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://[fd02:c9e3:a6c0:4306:0:0:0:27]:5500/jmx
```

and I get

> Connection did not succeed to ..

As for some background,

- I am running the jconsole from my Windows 7  box and connect to the jmx server on linux.
- the jmx server is a [dual stacked](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/net/ipv6_guide/#dual) Redhat linux  box and  I am able to connect through the jconsole using the IPv4 address.
- Not sure if this is relevant, the host I am trying to connect to has 2 network interfaces and one of them is used for management purposes only.

Comment: Just to check, do you have authentication setup on the client or disabled on the server?

Comment: Does you app actually listen on the IPv6 socket for jmx connections?

Comment: Did you check basic connectivity? Try `ping fd02:c9e3:a6c0:4306:0:0:0:27` first, then `telnet fd02:c9e3:a6c0:4306:0:0:0:27 5500` from the command prompt to see if the port is open (you'll get "connection refused" if not). Telnet can be installed via `Control Panel > Programs and Features > Turn Windows Features on or off > Telnet client` if it isn't already there.

Comment: @Heiko/Mike thanks for your inputs.  I figured that my server process needs to use '[]' to escape the ':' as part of the JMX URL.

Comment: @sfrocks: could you post the example of what you did? As far as I recall, you may answer your own post - and I sense it could be helpful to others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I added the below condition to wrap the server host address in square brackets.

```
    if ( aHost instanceof Inet4Address ) {
       this.hostAddress = aHost.getHostAddress();
    }
    else if ( aHost instanceof Inet6Address ) {
       this.hostAddress = "[" + aHost.getHostAddress() + "]";
    }
    else {
       throw someException();
    }

.............some other stuff.................

    registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry( this.hostAddress, ... );
```

---

In fact, the host address is specified as a name value pair in a properties file.  Hence I could have done like below but it didn't work for other reasons.

.properties file

hostName = [fd02:c9e3:a6c0:4306:0:0:0:27]

Comment: This would actually be wrong: the '[]' are required in the URL as per [RFC2732][1], they are not part of the host name.

  [1]: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2732